# The easiest way to know App Engine datastore's last change time

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to know when my app's data store was last updated.

Surely I could find and patch every line of code where queries INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE are used but may be there is such official capability in datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 'database service hook' to execute your own bit of code whenever the database is written to.

See http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/hooks.html

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against trying to accomplish this with an RPC hook. RPC hooks are neat, but they plug into relatively low-level components of the datastore stack. It's preferable to work with the high-level abstractions unless there's a good reason not to.

Why not just attach an update timestamp to your models?

```
class BaseModel(db.Model):
  updated_at = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)

class MyModel(BaseModel):
  name = db.StringProperty()

class OtherModel(BaseModel):
  total = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Every model that inherits from BaseModel will automatically track an update timestamp.

Comment: If I have 10 tables I will need to execute 10 SELECT queries to reach the goal, right?

Comment: What, specifically, is the goal?

Comment: That's still kinda vague. You want a single timestamp that shows the last time any entity has been updated? You want a list of all entities sorted by last update?

Comment: Bear in mind, too, that the datastore is a distributed system. Clocks on different machines will be off by small amounts, and there's really no way to define authoritatively which of two closely-timed events happened first.